# C# Winforms - Proper Memory Handling of Frequent String Templating

Tags: c#, string, templates, memory-management

I have a desktop application in C# that will take blocks of RTF text (of varying sizes, but probably upwards of ~20k in the larger blocks), and then swap out placeholder text with values from database records (e.g. "Dear [Name]," will become "Dear John Smith,"). For all intents and purposes of this question, imagine this to be a mail merge, and someone else is managing the templates, but C# will be reading the templates and merging in the values.

Now, I've read through several similar questions here on SO. I understand that strings are immutable, and it's my understanding that you can force-run GC to clean up unreferenced strings.

I don't want to use a 3rd party string-templating library to solve this because I want to get a better understanding and other opinions on what the proper mechanics should be here.

My current thought is to preprocess the templates into a List that might look like this (for example purposes I'm using plain text strings instead of RTF text):

```
List<string> lstTemplate = new List<string>()
{
  "The quick brown ",
  "[Animal1]",
  " jumped over the lazy ",
  "[Animal2]"
};
```

Then I would use a StringBuilder to assemble the pieces to avoid having lots of partial copies of the template in memory:

```
Dictionary<string,string> exampleDataRecord = new Dictionary<string,string>()
{
  { "[Animal1]", "fox" },
  { "[Animal2]", "dog" }
};

StringBuilder sbMerged = new StringBuilder();
foreach(string piece in lstTemplate)
{
  if((piece[0] == '[') && (piece[piece.Length-1] == ']'))
  {
    // Append the variable from the data record
    sbMerged.Append(exampleDataRecord[piece]);
  }
  else
  {
    // Append the template content
    sbMerged.Append(piece);
  }
}

// Display the final, merged result
rtfMyRichTextBox.Text = sbMerged.Text;
```

This process will likely be run thousands of times a day on average, so I figured I would keep the pre-processed string lists in memory for the duration of the application.

My question is - is this a good way to approach this problem without incurring lots of wasted memory or forcing GC? I figure that when the RTF textbox disposes, it will get rid of the merged text content, and the StringBuilder should avoid a ton of partially-built strings in memory.

However, I can't shake the feeling that I'm missing something, or maybe I've just been staring at it too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's an understanding of the mechanics that you seek, I'll provide an implementation.  And with this implementation, you can safely just **ignore memory management**.  Just let the GC do its thing.

I think the essence of the expanding code should look like this:

```
public string Expand(params string[] dynamics ) {
  string[][] tables = new string[][] { statics, dynamics };
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (var index in indices)
  {
    sb.Append(tables[index.Item1][index.Item2]);
  }
  return sb.ToString();
}
```

The idea is that there is an array of ***static strings*** containing the spans of text between the placeholders.  And there is an array of ***dynamic strings*** containing the text that is to be substituted for the given placeholder.  Then, when preprocessing your template, you construct both the array of static strings and an array of ***index pairs*** which refer to  the index in either the statics or dynamics array, using a two-dimensional index, where 0 is the statics and 1 is the dynamics.

For example, consider the template `"Hello, {0}. You are {1}! Thanks, {0}."` We have three static strings:

```
{ "Hello, ", ". You are ", "! Thanks, ", "." }
```

And the dynamics could be any one of the following examples:

```
{ "Adam", "a man" }
{ "Eve", "a woman" }
{ "jhilgeman", "cool" }
```

And the pre-processed indices array would look like this (below).  Note: I'll use simplified  `<a, b>` notation for the Tuple values rather than C#'s syntax of `Tuple.Create(a,b)`

```
{
   <0, 0>, // statics[0]   = "Hello, "
   <1, 0>, // dynamics[0]  = "Adam"
   <0, 1>, // statics[1]   = ". You are "
   <1, 1>, // dynamics[1]  = "a man"
   <0, 2>, // statics[2]   = "! Thanks, "
   <1, 0>, // dynamics[0]  = "Adam"  (reuses the same string)
   <0, 3>  // statics[3]   = "."
}
```

This technique uses the StringBuilder to assemble the final result quickly, and puts everything into arrays for uniform access to both the static portions of text and dynamic replacement strings that should perform quite efficiently.

I leave it up to you to come up with a suitable pre-processing strategy where you can choose your delimiters and escape characters, and how to deal with RTF formatting, and how to resolve things like [Name] to a table of replacement indices, and also how to build the replacement arrays, if they happen to come from a database.

But in the interest of completeness, here is a simple working example with plain-text:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Template
{
    public string Expand(params string[] dynamics)
    {
        string[][] tables = new string[][] { statics, dynamics };
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var index in indices)
        {
            sb.Append(tables[index.Item1][index.Item2]);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private Tuple<int, int>[] indices;
    private string[] statics;

    public Template(string source)
    {
        int last = 0;
        List<string> statics = new List<string>();
        List<Tuple<int, int>> indices = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(source, @"\{(\d+)\}"))
        {
            if (match.Index > last)
            {
                // emit a static portion
                indices.Add(Tuple.Create(0, statics.Count));
                statics.Add(source.Substring(last, match.Index - last));
            }
            // emit the dynamic portion
            indices.Add(Tuple.Create(1, int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value)));
            last = match.Index + match.Length;
        }
        // emit any leftovers
        if (last < source.Length)
        {
            indices.Add(Tuple.Create(0, statics.Count));
            statics.Add(source.Substring(last));
        }
        this.statics = statics.ToArray();
        this.indices = indices.ToArray();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Template t = new Template("Hello, {0}. You are {1}! Thanks, {0}.");

        Console.WriteLine(t.Expand("Adam", "a man"));
        Console.WriteLine(t.Expand("Eve", "a woman"));
        Console.WriteLine(t.Expand("jhilgeman", "cool"));
    }
}
```

Comment: How is that fundamentally different from what I have, aside from using List/Tuple instead of a Dictionary?

Comment: @jhilgeman, Your question is largely panic -- you seem to be worrying about a problem you don't have.  So I'm reassuring you that a high performance implementation works almost exactly like what you have - except that you normalize the string replacements to do integer look-ups rather than string searches/comparisons.  And you can get the expander to treat static and dynamic fragments similarly, which improves it a tiny bit further.  You should have no performance issues from the template expansion alone.

Comment: Okay. I'm less concerned about performance and more concerned about proper memory management, so if my approach is handling that aspect correctly per your comment, then that's my answer.

Comment: @jhilgeman, yes, I'll confirm again that your use of memory is fine in the parts you've shown or talked about.  I want to say explicitly that you haven't disclosed details of how you build your templates, but I'll assume that's out of scope.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to keep this limited to one question without too many tangents. Thanks!